# Add Multiple ZFS Pools to LVM

Tags: lvm, zfs

I'd like to just have one main "mount" for my data. I figure the best option is to present this via LVM. Can I use ZFS to create a few pools and then present that as one large LVM? Any issues with this setup?

Comment: Why do you want one main mount for your data?  Why do you prefer to create multiple zpools instead of a single large pool with one ZFS filesystem on it, and mount that?

Comment: @Malvineous Multiple zpools of different sizes

Comment: What's the benefit of multiple zpools of different sizes over one large zpool, when you want all the data to appear in the same mount point anyway?

Comment: Different size disks required different size pools

Comment: It's not a requirement to have all disks the same size in a zpool, it's just that the larger disks will see more writes than the smaller ones which could have a performance impact if the large disks also happen to be slow.  It would be interesting to find out whether the performance loss of using FUSE to merge the two filesystems is better or worse than having differently sized disks in the pool.  It probably depends on how big a variation there is from the largest to the smallest disk.

Comment: My concern was usable space not RW performance

Comment: I'm also super nervous of large zpools now as you can't manipulate properties of individual mirrors

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/577854/130767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO The best Option I found was "MergerFS" using Fuse. This allows me to still view/write/read directly to ZFS pools but view/access via one large mount point. No need to introduce something as complex as LVM, but I suspect it would work?

Comment: FUSE runs in user space so be aware that it can slow down your filesystem quite a lot.

Comment: This is all for my home server which is mostly write once and then read forever and I didn't notice a major performance loss, but yes good to understand if using FUSE

Comment: I've been using FUSE with UnionFS for my home server too for my home directory and it started out fine but I'm finding any program that scans the directory for files is very slow - some programs take 1-2 minutes to start instead of 2-3 seconds, so I'm planning to move away from using it on my home directory for that reason.  Not saying using it is a bad idea, just something to be aware of.

Comment: Ohh, I agree, I used Fuse mounts for like 1 day before I gave up. I don't care which software, fuse is a great idea but IMO not a good idea in the real world