# ZFS Recovery Mirror-0 UNAVAIL missing device

Tags: zfs, uuid

I'm new to ZFS and I screwed things up big time. I had multiple ZFS pools because I didn't realize you could have separate mirrors under the same pool. I am still rebuilding array, so one of my mirrors was emtpy. I destroyed it, added it to the main pool and all was well.

I then went to set the read property of that mirror to readonly and was unable. I then tried to remove just that mirror, but was unable. Finally, I tried exporting the pool and I wrote over the 2nd mirror (which had no data) and tried to import the main pool. My thoughts where it would show up as that mirror was missing/degraded but the 1st mirror would be OK, not so lucky. I now can not import the zpool at all, even though (I suspect) mirror-0 is functioning correctltly.

I'm wondering if there is a way I can hack about this? I was thinking of manually setting the UUID/PARTUUID of the extra mirror just to get it to import, but of course everything online is about ext4 and I didn't find a way to manipulate the UUID for ZFS.

Is there any ways you can think of I can force this to import or remove zpools expectation of the second mirror so it mounts the first one? Or finally, moving the mirror-0 to it's own zpool without destroying data?

Feeling lost...

Here is some data:

zpool name `bigdataa`

```
mirror-0 should have a functionion set of data

 pool: bigdataa
     id: 8521961398473378259
  state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E
 config:

    bigdataa                                  UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
      mirror-0                                ONLINE
        12d9fdf5-9912-4b47-a67c-73376cabe161  ONLINE
        0f8cbe38-fce7-ba4d-85fb-f0b624ef4c70  ONLINE
      615ac488-0519-4a31-88ea-ddc81595c9b7    ONLINE
      mirror-2                                UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
        aef43ae1-2bff-4eac-8c91-7818b1ec37fd  FAULTED  corrupted data
        8d1e0a1e-9736-4a28-a968-555fe65e9d17  FAULTED  corrupted data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did extensive research and was unable to find a way to mount the pool. I will be keeping seperate pools moving forward so I can maniuplate properties of individual mirrors and mount single mirrors when there is no issue ( not impressed with how this worked...) and using MergeFS to present a final single pool.

I did try UFS Explorer RAID Recovery (all that I ended up needing was UFS Explorer Recovery which was $70CAD, much easier to swallow and now I have a great piece of software in my toolkit) and after last night, it finished the scan and seems to have found all my files. I'll be taking the $200CAD pricetag and update with final results, but things look good!

Update: I'm currently saving all my files so far everything looks great. Ironically, I realized I didn't even need to "scan for lost files" as the Partition/File structure was never altered, it seems somehow this software is able to view individual disks in a mirror without "importing" the pool or having the other disks available. (I confirmed this by not scanning, but just going straight to "view files" on my other mirror disks)

I guess these guys have no idea what they are talking about... I hate people who just troll with negative/useless feedback...

https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/recovery-tool-for-zfs.23008/post-138885

[image]

Comment: With ZFS : performance is decided by the disk arrangement and the demands on resiliency in face of disk error. Properties: in the pool you can create an hierarchy of datasets/filesystems there inheritance of properties can be employed.  How many disks did you have available ? Were they the same with regards to size ? you could create vdevs with 5 disks in each and Z2 as the scheme: in that case you can lose 2 disks in each vdev completely without dataloss --- bevare that you can't lose one more while recovering from the errors - what is DoS until backup data is deployed (or data loss.)

Answer (score -1):

The way you have constructed it here shows that your data is striped (RAID-0) across mirror-0, mirror-2 and another disk.  So when you overwrote mirror-2, ZFS thought half your data was lost and that's why you couldn't import the pool at all.  It would be like you set up a three disk RAID-0 array and then wiped one of the disks - all the data becomes inaccessible because that's how striping works.

This explains why you were unable to set the readonly property on mirror-2 as well.  It would be like trying to mark one disk in your RAID-0 array as read only, which can't be done as writes need to be striped across all the disks in the RAID-0 array.  You can't mark every third block on your storage device as read only!

It looks like you had no data on mirror-2 yet, but it seems ZFS didn't know that which is why it refused to import the array after the disk was overwritten.

I think maybe you are assuming all the devices/vdevs in the pool are mirrors of each other, but actually ZFS stripes data across each vdev in the pool.  This is why you have to create a special mirror vdev if you want the data mirrored rather than striped.

Comment: All I know is ZFS was 100% unable to rescue my data and UFS made it seem trivial. I am just exploring moving from mdadm and am unimpressed with zfs disaster recovery capability. Mature/Trusted raid software is worth as much as the features of said software. I'm 100% confident I could have recovered my data without paying money for a third-party software if I had a done the same thing using mdadm

Comment: Did you try to force-import the pool?  I would've expected that to work and would've recovered your data, minus any files that may have made it to the lost disk.

Comment: I consider myself a fairly competent sysadmin and trust me when I say I did spend a full night frustrated trying to "force import" to no avail.

Comment: Haha don't take it the wrong way, I only ask because you didn't mention it in the original post nor what errors it came up with, which could've helped work out what the problem was.

Comment: Sorry but mirror is not striped. Those were created using the mirror command

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers You have two mirrors yes (with two disks in each mirror), but you have set them up so that data is striped across the two mirrors (effectively two disks mirroring stripe 1, two other disks mirroring stripe 2), that is why things did not work the way you expected when you wiped one mirror set.  If you disagree, please show me where it says in your output that `mirror-0` and `mirror-2` are copies of each other, because the output you posted shows them as having ZFS split the data across the two mirrors, with some written to `mirror-0` and some written to `mirror-2`.